# UTC t to local time junk data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, nsdate

```
 let estDf = DateFormatter()
 let gmtDf = DateFormatter()

 gmtDf.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
 gmtDf.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd','HH:mm:ss"
 let time_ = "2017-10-21,10:53:23"
 let utcDate = gmtDf.date(from: time_)!
 print("UTC :",utcDate)

 let timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent.identifier as String

 estDf.timeZone =  TimeZone(identifier: timeZone)
 estDf.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd','HH:mm:ss"
 let estDate = estDf.date(from: gmtDf.string(from: utcDate))!

 print("Local time",estDate)
```

While convert from UTC time format to local time format, time is showing one hour after.

So if the UTC time is

```
  2017-10-21 10:53:23 +0000
```

local time time showing as

```
 2017-10-21 10:53:23 +0000
```

But the actual time in the device is :

```
 2017-10-21 9:53:23 +0000
```

Comment: What is declared as the `time_` variable?

Comment: @LWJ updated the question,

Comment: You don't need to set the time zone of a date formatter if you want it to be the local TZ; it takes that value by default.

Comment: @JoshCaswell i'm receiving the time_ in UTC, so there i'm setting the time zone as UTC.

Comment: The behavior is correct based on the code you've written. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm talking about `estDf.timeZone = TimeZone(identifer: timeZone)`

Comment: @JoshCaswell right now i,m getting the local time as 1 hour pre.

Comment: @Joe are you trying to convert the timezone from UTC to local time and print it?

Comment: @LWJ yes, exactly

Comment: @Joe Don't use that Swift version. It is a totally wrong approach.